# Django Rest Framework serializer is ignoring the model instance im trying to serialize

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I´m trying to create an instance of a serializer on a POST request, but it is ignoring the model instance im passing as the first argument

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if string_pk in reviewed_user_pk:
            reviewed_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
            review = Review(author=user, reviewed_user=reviewed_user)
            serializer = CreateReviewSerializer(review, data=request.data)
```

I get user instance from the request:

```
    try:
        user = request.user
    except user.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

The problem here is that  the instance of Review which has both user instances (author and reviewed_user) is being ignored by the ReviewSerializer, here is the serializer:

```
class CreateReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['author', 'reviewed_user','title',  'rating', 'comment', 'date_published']
```

The oter fields in request.data are being serialized but not the Review instance, what can be causing this problem? the error i get from serializer.errors is the following:

```
{
    "author": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "reviewed_user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Here is the complete function view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def api_create_review_view(request, user_pk): #user_pk is the pk of the reviewed_user
    try:
        user = request.user
    except user.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    reviewed_user_pk = user.worked_with.split(',')
    string_pk = str(user_pk)
    data = {

    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if string_pk in reviewed_user_pk:
            reviewed_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
            review = Review(author=user, reviewed_user=reviewed_user)
            serializer = ReviewSerializer(review, data=request.data)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()

                reviews_count = reviewed_user.reviews_count
                rating = ((reviewed_user.rating * reviews_count) / (reviews_count + 1)) + ((serializer.rating) / (reviews_count + 1))

                reviews_count += 1
                reviewed_user.rating = rating
                reviewed_user.reviews_count = reviews_count
                reviewed_user.save()

                return Response(serializer.data)
            data = serializer.errors
            return Response(data)
        else:
            data = {
                'forbidden':'users have not worked together'
            }
            return Response(data=data)
```

And here is the Review model:

```
class Review(models.Model):

    reviewed_user =     models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviewed_user')
    author =            models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    rating =            models.IntegerField(default=5)
    title =             models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment =           models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_published =    models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Right now im not worried that the code inside the if statement that checks if the serializer is valid works, i just want to know how can i pass the instance of Review with both user instances inside to the serializer so the serializer is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are try to create a new instance of Review. Try this two method, i am not sure which one can work.

first way, change the request.data:

```
from copy import deepcopy

reviewed_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)

serializer_data = deepcopy(request.data)
serializer_data['user'] = user
serializer_data['reviewed_user'] = reviewed_user

serializer = ReviewSerializer(serializer_data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

second way,just change serializer to partial with set `partial=partial` in Serializer:

```
reviewed_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
review = Review(author=user, reviewed_user=reviewed_user)
serializer = ReviewSerializer(review, data=request.data, partial=partial)

if serializer.is_valid():
```

third way, not validate user and reviewed_user in serializer, just save it,
remove 'author', 'reviewed_user' in serializer:

```
class CreateReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['title',  'rating', 'comment', 'date_published']

reviewed_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
serializer = ReviewSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(author=user, reviewed_user=reviewed_user) # save user and reviewed_user here
```

Comment: Thank you, the 3rd solution did the trick! i still don't know why the serializer was ignoring the Review instance, but i guess we'll never know lol